# Unnecessary grid lines in sobel filter Opengl ES

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, raspberry-pi

My aim is to create sobel filter in Opengl ES. I am using Netbeans IDE. Everything is working fine in debug mode but in release mode I am getting grid lines. The code is running on raspberry pi.

Can anyone help me get rid of these lines?

This is the fragment shader code.

```
varying vec2 tcoord;
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform vec2 texelsize;
void main(void) 
{
    vec4 tm1m1 = texture2D(tex,tcoord+vec2(-1,-1)*texelsize);
    vec4 tm10 = texture2D(tex,tcoord+vec2(-1,0)*texelsize);
    vec4 tm1p1 = texture2D(tex,tcoord+vec2(-1,1)*texelsize);
    vec4 tp1m1 = texture2D(tex,tcoord+vec2(1,-1)*texelsize);
    vec4 tp10 = texture2D(tex,tcoord+vec2(1,0)*texelsize);
    vec4 tp1p1 = texture2D(tex,tcoord+vec2(1,1)*texelsize);
    vec4 t0m1 = texture2D(tex,tcoord+vec2(0,-1)*texelsize);
    vec4 t0p1 = texture2D(tex,tcoord+vec2(0,-1)*texelsize);

    vec4 xdiff = -1.0*tm1m1 + -2.0*tm10 + -1.0*tm1p1 + 1.0*tp1m1 + 2.0*tp10 + 1.0*tp1p1;
    vec4 ydiff = -1.0*tm1m1 + -2.0*t0m1 + -1.0*tp1m1 + 1.0*tm1p1 + 2.0*t0p1 + 1.0*tp1p1;
    vec4 tot = sqrt((xdiff*xdiff)+(ydiff*ydiff));

    vec4 col = tot;
    col.a = 1.0;

    gl_FragColor = clamp(col,vec4(0),vec4(1));
}
```

This is Debug image.
[image: Debug image]

Release image.
[image: Release image]

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer. I did notice a wrong sign in your shader:

```
vec4 t0m1 = texture2D(tex,tcoord+vec2(0,-1)*texelsize);
vec4 t0p1 = texture2D(tex,tcoord+vec2(0,-1)*texelsize);
```

Those two would be the same value. Following the pattern of the other values, this should be:

```
vec4 t0m1 = texture2D(tex,tcoord+vec2(0,-1)*texelsize);
vec4 t0p1 = texture2D(tex,tcoord+vec2(0,1)*texelsize);
```

I don't believe this would explain the grid lines, though. But it should certainly improve the quality of the result.

Comment: Only while compiling with -Ox flags it gives problems. x=1,2,3

Comment: How the CPU code is compiled shouldn't really influence what happens in the shader. Is the texture ok if you simply sample it in the shader, without any of the filtering calculations?

Comment: Yes,the texture looks ok without any filter.

Comment: If I output 'tp10' output is fine, if I output 'tm10' output is fine but when I do 'tp10 - tm10' I get lines.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the full code of fragment shader? This looks like it may be caused by low precision.

According to p. 4.5.3 of [GLSL ES tech specs](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) you must explicitly specify float precision for fragment shaders - certain OpenGL ES drivers can even fail to compile fragment shaders w/o float precision.

You can set precision with this instruction at the very beginning of shader:

```
precision highp float;
```

Comment: Adding 'precision highp float;' didn't make any difference.I did it to all the shaders.